# Should I create a separate database table for temporary users

Tags: database, database-design

I have a user table that controls access to a website. We currently have a few hundred users and this might eventually grow to a few 10,000s. We have a requirement to allow in "temporary" users. These temporary users will have a token that times out, never to be used again. These tokens will likely outnumber the general users by a great degree. The question I have is whether these temporary users should be stored in the general table or in their own table.

My inclination is the same table as the userid is used elsewhere as foreign keys and is still useful for a temporary user. The uniqueness across the ids would be important. However, I'm not delighted that the user table will be filled with many records that never again need to be used and will thus slow down the table.

Another option I've considered is to create a user record, capture the id, delete the record and then use the id in another table. I therefore retain the uniqueness of the id but reduce the bloating of the table. I don't mind if the foreign keys reference different tables.

Anyone had a similar issue and have any thoughts?

Comment: you might also want to ask that question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd stick them in the same place if they perform the same database functionality.  regarding the bloat, could the records simply be purged after the token expires (or a few weeks/months/years after or do you need to retain their data?) or add a status column "inactive", indexed and always filter by it.  as non-temp users leave deleted adds value there too.

Comment: I might also ask on dba, but you've given me reassurance that I wasn't missing something obvious. It just felt slightly wrong (and still does), but I couldn't find a substantial technical argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you index the ID or have it as primary key the size of the table should not impact performance.

I would advise leaving the user record there to retain foreign key constraints if required - adding foreign keys will improve performance when retrieving data too as opposed to "soft" foreign keys.

IF it makes sense, you could separate users from temporary users.

Comment: "adding foreign keys will improve performance" depends on the dbms. PostgreSQL's query planner, for example, doesn't take foreign key declarations into account at all. (They have *no* effect on SELECT performance.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same table. As for the performance problem: add a column that says 'temporary' and whenever you don't want temporary users just filter it to 'false'. That will not slow down the table (more so if you also add an index to that table.)

Answer (score 1):

> We currently have a few hundred users and this might eventually grow
>   to a few 10,000s.

So you're thinking of 30,000 to 40,000 users. Unless your user table is badly designed or poorly indexed, 10 times that many users shouldn't have much performance impact. But asking this question on SO is not the best way to approach the problem.

The best way is to build a users table on a development computer, populate it with 10 times what you expect, and test it. I did that here. It took me 1:53 (one minute, 53 seconds), and that included stopping for a moment to tend my cup of tea. Selecting one user took 0.049ms, and it used an index scan.

Here's how you might do that using PostgreSQL.

```
create table users (
  user_id integer primary key,
  user_name varchar(15) not null default '01234567890123',
  -- Use as many other text columns as you need. For testing your scenario,
  -- the values don't matter. They just make the table wider, slower, and
  -- more realistic.
  other_text_1 varchar(30) not null default '01234567890123456789012345678'
);

insert into users (user_id)
select generate_series(1,300000);

analyze users;

explain analyze
select * 
from users
where user_id = 200676;

Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.00..8.30 rows=1 width=49) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (user_id = 200676)
Total runtime: 0.049 ms
```

For more complex or more random data, use a scripting language. (Perl, ruby, python . . .)